# Prime ideals in a quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> I am interested in finding the number of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(12,x^2+1)$.

Here is what I think. Modding out by $x^2+1$, we get $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(12)$. Factoring $12$ in the Gaussian integers, we get $3(1+i)^2(1-i)^2$. Then we have four primes $(0)$, $(1+i)$, $(1-i)$ and $(3)$. Is this about right?

Comment: Use correspondence theorem (sometimes called third isomorphism theorem) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem_2

Comment: Note that $1+i = i\cdot (1-i)$, hence $(1+i) = (1-i)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the ideal $(1 + i) = (1 - i)$ because the generators are associate!